# Canvas text with animate bg

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

Hi i found nice effect http://www.wandi-studio.com/Home/Welcome — animate text bg. (animated background with titles HYT WATCHES, LE BATAFOR, MAURICE LACROIX)

This site uses mootools as js framework, I would like to use JQuery.

**Maybe some one give me tips how to make this effect?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use canvas’s context.globalCompositeOperation to overwrite text with the an image.**

Then you can get the movement effect you want by animating the image’s x-offset.

This code will draw text on the canvas and then overwrite **just the text** with the image.

```
// first draw the text on the canvas
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.font="144pt Verdana";
      ctx.fillText("See",30,200);
      ctx.fill();


      // use compositing to draw the background image
      // only where the text has been drawn
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";
      ctx.drawImage(img,-x,0);
```

Of course you'll want to stylize with your own text font, background image and animation pattern.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MrVJB/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ padding:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red; position:absolute}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){


    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var xOffset=100; // image offset
    var fps=60;

    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.onload=function(){
       animate();
    }
    img.src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/23400000/water-water-23444632-2048-1277.jpg";

    function draw(x){

            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();

            // put text on canvas
            ctx.font="144pt Verdana";
            ctx.fillText("See",30,200);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.beginPath();

            // use compositing to draw the background image
            // only where the text has been drawn
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";
            ctx.drawImage(img,-x,0);
            ctx.restore();
    }


        function animate() {

            // change the background image offset
            xOffset+=3;
            if(xOffset>=img.width){xOffset=0;}

            // draw the text and background image
            draw(xOffset);

            // request another frame using fps intervals
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                // Drawing code goes here
            }, 1000 / fps);
        }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
     <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Good job! This is a very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

I see here for example this solution:

You need create images where letters will be **transparent**. Using position you also set jQuery animation "under" this image where object (in this case another image) moving to right and back in loop.

This should help you on start.

Comment: It is simple, but not a universal solution. If you inspect site code you will see uses canvas + mootools script.

Comment: When you are programmer you can always find more than one solution to problem. I just show you mine vision for this. I can't give entire solution. Maybe if I found little more time I will show you what I mean with my answer.